# Android - Changing language on the fly

Tags: android, locale

I am trying to switch between 2 languages in a `Spinner` in my `Activity`, "English" and "French".

I have my `values` folder and `values-fr` and within these folder I have a file called `string_my_activity.xml` which contains strings for the one activity I want to translate on the fly.

For the `Spinner`, I am populating it with a string array in my normal strings.xml currently (I will translate this later).

I have been using samples from StackOverflow which say to either use a `LocaleHelper` or a `CustomContextWrapper`. However, neither are working. I think the problem is how I'm using them, as other people have had success.

When I try to use them in `onItemSelected` in my `Spinner`, nothing happens obviously. I do a `recreate()` on the activity but all the current strings are still the default language.

I'm using the `ContextWrapper`:

```
public class CustomContextWrapper extends ContextWrapper {
    public CustomContextWrapper(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static ContextWrapper wrap(Context context, String language) {
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        Locale sysLocale;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            sysLocale = getSystemLocale(config);
        } else {
            sysLocale = getSystemLocaleLegacy(config);
        }
        if (!language.equals("") && !sysLocale.getLanguage().equals(language)) {
            Locale locale = new Locale(language);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                setSystemLocale(config, locale);
            } else {
                setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
            }

            context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }

        return new ContextWrapper(context);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static Locale getSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config) {
        return config.locale;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public static Locale getSystemLocale(Configuration config) {
        return config.getLocales().get(0);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void setSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config, Locale locale) {
        config.locale = locale;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public static void setSystemLocale(Configuration config, Locale locale) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
    }
}
```

and the `LocaleHelper`:

```
public class LocaleHelper {

    private static final String TAG = LocaleHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";
    public static final String DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = "en";

    public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAttach(context)");
        String lang = getStoredLanguage(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
//        String lang = getStoredLanguage(context, DEFAULT_LANGUAGE);
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAttach(context, language)");
        String lang = getStoredLanguage(context, defaultLanguage);
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
        return getStoredLanguage(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    }

    public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Setting locale: " + language);
        saveLanguage(context, language);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResources(context, language);
        }

        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
    }

    private static String getStoredLanguage(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
    }

    private static void saveLanguage(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
        editor.apply();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Log.d(TAG, "updateResources::" + language);
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Log.d(TAG, "updateResources:: Getting config");

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

        Log.d(TAG, "updateResources:: Creating config context");
        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
        Log.d(TAG, "updateResourcesLegacy");
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
        }

        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        return context;
    }

    public static Locale getLocale(Configuration config) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return getSystemLocale(config);
        } else {
            return getSystemLocaleLegacy(config);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Locale getSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config) {
        return config.locale;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static Locale getSystemLocale(Configuration config) {
        return config.getLocales().get(0);
    }
}
```

But haven't been able to get either of them working.

In my `Activity` I am using them like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {
    String newLang = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
    Log.e(TAG, "onItemSelected: " + newLang);

    Locale currentLocale = LocaleHelper.getLocale(getResources().getConfiguration());
    Locale newLocale = new Locale(newLang);
    if (!currentLocale.getLanguage().equalsIgnoreCase(newLocale.getLanguage())) {
        Log.e(TAG, String.format("Changing language from %s to %s", currentLocale.getLanguage(), newLocale.getLanguage()));
        LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, newLang);
        Log.d(TAG, "Recreating activity");
        recreate();
    }
}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    Log.d(TAG, "attachBaseContext");
    String lang = LocaleHelper.getLanguage(newBase);
    Log.e(TAG, "attachBaseContext::setting language::" + lang);
    super.attachBaseContext(CustomContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, lang));
}
```

The best I can get is the languages showing up in the Logs, but not being reflected in the UI. At the moment, it always seems to get the default language "en", which is another problem.

So my question is, how do I get the UI to update itself?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I find this code over the internet and it is working perfectly fine for me take a look if it will do the trick for you as well, modify it according to your spinner

```
 languagebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    LocaleManager.setNewLocale(language.this, LocaleManager.LANGUAGE_KEY_ENGLISH);

                String languageToLoad  = LocaleManager.LANGUAGE_KEY_ENGLISH; // your language
                Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                try {
                    ActivityInfo info = getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(getComponentName(), GET_META_DATA);
                    if (info.labelRes != 0) {
                        setTitle(info.labelRes);
                    }
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });
```

LocaleManager.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Build;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

import java.util.Locale;

public class LocaleManager {
    /**
     * For english locale
     */
    public static final String LANGUAGE_KEY_ENGLISH = "en";
    /**
     * for hindi locale
     */
    public static final String LANGUAGE_KEY_HINDI = "hi";
    /***
     * // for spanish locale
     */
    private static final String LANGUAGE_KEY = "language_key";

    /**
     * set current pref locale
     * @param mContext
     * @return
     */
    public static Context setLocale(Context mContext) {
        return updateResources(mContext, getLanguagePref(mContext));
    }

    /**
     * Set new Locale with context
     * @param mContext
     * @param mLocaleKey
     * @return
     */
    public static Context setNewLocale(Context mContext, String mLocaleKey) {
        setLanguagePref(mContext, mLocaleKey);
        return updateResources(mContext, mLocaleKey);
    }

    /**
     * Get saved Locale from SharedPreferences
     * @param mContext current context
     * @return current locale key by default return english locale
     */
    public static String getLanguagePref(Context mContext) {
        SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        return mPreferences.getString(LANGUAGE_KEY, LANGUAGE_KEY_ENGLISH);
    }

    /**
     *  set pref key
     * @param mContext
     * @param localeKey
     */
    private static void setLanguagePref(Context mContext, String localeKey) {
        SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        mPreferences.edit().putString(LANGUAGE_KEY, localeKey).commit();
    }

    /**
     * update resource
     * @param context
     * @param language
     * @return
     */
    private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            config.setLocale(locale);
            context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
        } else {
            config.locale = locale;
            res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        }
        return context;
    }

    /**
     * get current locale
     * @param res
     * @return
     */
    public static Locale getLocale(Resources res) {
        Configuration config = res.getConfiguration();
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24 ? config.getLocales().get(0) : config.locale;
    }
}
```

Comment: Create different string files for different languages and load content from that to your text views and make sure to restart activity or send the app to the new screen so the new resource can be load